# Liquibase classcastException with mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, liquibase

Getting this exception :

```
class liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase cannot be cast to class liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase (liquibase.database.core.UnsupportedDatabase and liquibase.nosql.database.AbstractNoSqlDatabase are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

My changelog file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="liquibase">
        <ext:dropCollection collectionName="dummy"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Any solutions on this?

Comment: Either you are making an illegal cast or you may not have this library installed correctly. Make sure that you are casting your objects in the right way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.